# The type '' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method ''. There is no implicit reference conversion from '' to ''

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, generics

I generated Linq -to -Entity model from database and modified it - I've made interface :

```
public interface IValid
{
    byte Valid{ get; set; } 
}
```

and make some generated classes to inherit this interface.

I've wrote generic class to access tables from database:

```
public List<T> GetValidRecords<T>() where T: class, IValid
{
    try
    {
        return _context.Set<T>().Where(x => x.Valid == 1).ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

When I call this method in my unit test

```
var records = repositary.GetValidRecords<tableName>();
```

I get error -

> The type 'tableName' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'GetValidRecords()'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'tableName' to 'IValid'.

How to fix it?

EDIT:
my table class:

```
public partial class tableName: IValid    {
    public byte IsValid { get; set; } 
}
```

EDIT2: 
My calling method:

```
public void GetValidRecordsGenericTest()
{
    var data = new List<tableName>
    {
        new tableName() {Valid = 1},
        new tableName() {Valid = 1}
    }.AsQueryable();

    var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<tableName>>();
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<tableName>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<tableName>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<tableName>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<tableName>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());           var mockContext = new Mock<Entities>();
    mockContext.Setup(x => x.tableNames).Returns(mockSet.Object);

    var database = new Database(mockContext.Object);
    var records = database.GetValidRecords<tableName>(); // here I get error

    Assert.AreEqual(2, records.Count, "Wrong number of gueltig records.");
}
```

Comment: Make sure `tableName` is the name of a type implementing IValid.

Comment: @helb You should probably post that as an answer, because it is the answer. :)

Comment: @helb my table implement this interface

Comment: @helb, yes, it is the same method, I've changed it already

Comment: Sorry, I'm at a loss here. I don't see what could be wrong. Re-open and rebuild everything and see if the rror persists.

Comment: @helb. I donno why, but I recreated Interface end error dissapeared. Thnk for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tableName` should be something like this for it to work:

```
class tableName : IValid
{
    // implement IValid
}
```

Also make sure that the class `tableName` implements the same IValid interface as used in the method `GetValidRecords`, i.e. the `IValid` from the correct namespace.

Comment: I have public partial class tableName: IValid

Comment: @Sasha Then make sure it is the same IValid (are there other IValid interfaces in your project?)

Comment: Yes, it's only interface with such name. Can be the Problem, that this table class is generated with Entity Framework?

Comment: As long as it implements the *proper* `IValid` interface, then no. Do feel free to show more code in your question such as the actual class that implements `IValid` - I just tried this construct for myself to double check, and it compiles without problems.

Comment: @Sasha Strange. There must be something wrong in the method where you call `GetValidRecords`. Please post this code.